# What does Visual Studio for Mac use to host applications?

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-mac

When you hit the run button in Visual Studio for Mac, what service is it that actually temporarily runs the website? So for example if I ran the application in Windows the site would be running under Local IIS (assuming I had nothing else configured) - is there a Local IIS equivalent for Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: Kestrel is able to run on its own. There is no IIS/IIS Express on Mac.

Comment: VS for Mac runs your ASP.NET Core app with dotnet. For classic ASP.NET it uses [xsp](https://github.com/mono/xsp), which is a C# web server which ships with Mono.